# Parallel MSBuilds fail in Jenkins pipeline file

Tags: parallel-processing, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

I've noticed that whenever I attempt to build my .NET solution scripted within the jenkins file, on different nodes in parallel, one of the builds is successful but the others fail. My setup is as follows:

```
    "Pipeline A": {
                node {

                stage('Git clone') {
                    checkout scm
                }

                stage('Build') {

                    powershell '".paket\\paket.bootstrapper.exe"'    
                    powershell '".\\paket_install.bat"'
                    bat '"msbuild" iGCAutomation.sln"'
                }

                },
                "Pipeline B": {
                node {      

                    stage('Git clone') {

                        checkout scm
                    }

                    stage('Build') {

                        powershell '".paket\\paket.bootstrapper.exe"'    
                        powershell '".\\paket_install.bat"'
                        bat '"msbuild" iGCAutomation.sln"'

                    }
```

You get my drift.

In the logs I did see this suggestion, which I tried but didn't actually work.

*Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.*

So for Pipeline A, paket downloads the necessary dependencies and moves on to execute some other stage. In pipeline B, the build fails.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: In the log file I get this suggestion (which I've already tried to add within the script)  _italic_Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch._italic_ As such what I am doing is first downloading all the dependencies using paket, then build the solution afterwards. For the first node this worked out well.. however for pipeline B the same steps failed.

Comment: This issue was fixed from my part by fixing the powershell commands.

Comment: How does the command look now? Just in case somebody has the same problem and finds your question.